# Convert sf object to dataframe and restore it to original state

Tags: r, r-sf

I'd like to convert a `sf` object to a `dataframe` and restore it to its original state. But when I make the conversion of `st_as_text(st_sfc(stands_sel$geometry))` is shows very difficult to retrieve it again. In my example:

```
library(sf)

# get AOI in shapefile
download.file(
  "https://github.com/Leprechault/trash/raw/main/sel_stands_CMPC.zip",
  zip_path <- tempfile(fileext = ".zip")
)
unzip(zip_path, exdir = tempdir())

# Open the file
setwd(tempdir())
stands_sel <- st_read("sel_stands_CMPC.shp")
st_crs(stands_sel) = 4326

# Extract geometry as text
geom <- st_as_text(st_sfc(stands_sel$geometry))

# Add the features
features <- st_drop_geometry(stands_sel)
str(features)

# Joining feature + geom 
geo_df <- cbind(features, geom)
str(geo_df)
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  17 variables:
#  $ CD_USO_SOL: num  2433 9053
#  $ ID_REGIAO : num  11 11
#  $ ID_PROJETO: chr  "002" "344"
#  $ PROJETO   : chr  "BARBA NEGRA" "CAMPO SECO"
#  $ CD_TALHAO : chr  "159A" "016A"
#  $ CARACTERIS: chr  "Plantio Comercial" "Plantio Comercial"
#  $ CARACTER_1: chr  "Produtivo" "Produtivo"
#  $ CICLO     : int  2 1
#  $ ROTACAO   : int  1 1
#  $ DATA_PLANT: chr  "2008/04/15" "2010/04/15"
#  $ LOCALIDADE: chr  "BARRA DO RIBEIRO" "DOM FELICIANO"
#  $ ESPACAMENT: chr  "3.00 x 2.50" "3.5 x 2.14"
#  $ ESPECIE   : chr  "SALIGNA" "DUNNI"
#  $ SISTEMA_PR: chr  "MACRO ESTACA - EUCALIPTO" "SEMENTE - EUCALIPTO"
#  $ VLR_AREA  : num  8.53 28.07
#  $ ID_UNIQUE : chr  "BARBANEGRA159A" "CAMPOSECO016A"
#  $ geom      : chr  "MULTIPOLYGON (((-51.21423 -30.35172, -51.21426 -30.35178, -51.2143 -30.35181, -51.21432 -30.35186, -51.21433 -3"| __truncated__ 

# Return to original format again
stands_sf <- geo_df %>% 
                        st_geometry(geom) %>% 
                             sf::st_as_sf(crs = 4326)
#Error in UseMethod("st_geometry") :
```

Please, any help to restore my `stands_sf` object to the orinal state?

Comment: When setting geometry (at the end), try this instead: `st_as_sf(geo_df, wkt = "geom", crs = 4326)`

Comment: You're welcome! Would you mind if I post this as an answer so it is easier for future readers to find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `geom` isn't in a format `st_geometry` is expecting. `st_as_text` converted your geometry into WKT as discussed in the help:

> The returned WKT representation of simple feature geometry conforms to the simple features access specification and extensions, known as EWKT, supported by PostGIS and other simple features implementations for addition of SRID to a WKT string.

https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/st_as_text.html

Instead, use `st_as_sf(wkt=)` to set the new (old) geometry.

```
st_as_sf(geo_df, wkt = "geom", crs = 4326)
```